# Unable to install multiple things due to libarary problems

Tags: apt, wine, playonlinux, libraries

I wanted to install `libsdl2-dev` and `PlayOnLinux`. I use `aptitude` as my package manager. When trying

```
sudo aptitude install libsdl2-dev
```

I get [this](https://pastebin.com/uLtZkes2). If I ask for another solution I get [this](https://pastebin.com/yrt5Hag1) which is an even worse solution. With PlayOnLinux I get [this](https://pastebin.com/dnAsaKD1). I have no idea why this is happening but I'm guessing these two issues are related. Any help would be appriciated, and any info that can be used to help resolve this can be given.

Dependecies for these things: https://pastebin.com/TCt59sjK

Another edit: SO I still haven't found a solution but I think I found the problem has to do with some packages needing the :amd64 version but another one already had the :i386 one installed and as such they conflict.

Edit: Im so stupid, I didn't have xenial-updates enabled, only xenial-security

Comment: Any reason you can't use apt? Have you tried `apt install -f`?

Comment: Also is there any reason you're dumping all this into pastebins rather than pasting them directly into your question with code formatting?  (Saves us havingn to go to Javascript- and ad-laden websites just to see your outputs)

Comment: @ThomasWard Some of the things are multiple hundred lines, I think the last link is over 800 lines. Figured that pastebin would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into software updates and turn on xenial-updates. I had only xenial-security checked. Everything now works fine